# Esri WPF SDK wont build with a error

Tags: c#, wpf, arcgis, esri

I downloaded The ESRI WPF SDK and the all necessary stuff for it and installed it.

I downloaded the interactive sample Application that they provide. Opened the solution for the first time and the build went without any problems.

Several days later I did not want to compile. First it could not resolve the System.Windows.Interactivity dependency. After solving it I got the following error.

Build error:

> Error 1   Unknown build error, 'Cannot resolve dependency to assembly
>   'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' because it has not been preloaded.
>   When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be
>   pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the
>   ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.'     ArcGISWPFSDK

OutputWindow:

> ------ Build started: Project: ArcGISWPFSDK, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFX.targets(268,9):
>   error MC1000: Unknown build error, 'Cannot resolve dependency to
>   assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' because it has not been preloaded.
>   When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be
>   pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the
>   ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.' 
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

For the last 5 days I am googeling this error but nothing works. Please, help someone. I am loosing my mind.

This are the WPF sampels

Comment: Which .net framework version are you targeting in your projects? Sounds like some of the projects in your solution may have the wrong application options selected.

Comment: It is one project in the whole solution. .NET 4.0 (not client profile)

Comment: Are any of your 3rd party libraries using a DI container that needs to be configured for it to resolve dependencies?

Comment: nope. the ones that the ESRI sdk provides only

Comment: Do you have a reference to 'System.Windows' in the References for the sample project? Sounds basic, but everyone in a while I'll have to re-add references that haven't changed.

Comment: Also are you trying to build on .net 4.5?

Comment: Yes, I had. Just found the solution. I will never understand, why I always find the solution on my own after asking posting here a question. Thanks anyway

I answered it below

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

For some stupid reason, The Blend SDK did not want to install the WPF components, but only the Silverlight dependancies.

When I was adding the interactivity.dll reference I was "searching" for it and just coppied the path. Since there was only one present I assumed it must have been the needed one.

This error says that in a WPF application I am trying to use a silverlight dll